# First closed question has default fields in explanation

Tags: bug, status-completed

See < https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134652/foundations-of-mathematics-and-set-theory>, where the reasons for closing are slightly too relevant/not relevant at all. How many of these fields are there that we still need to fill in?

Comment: I see "Questions on Empty are expected to generally relate to , within the scope defined in the faq," which is more than a little weird.

Comment: Maybe it should have said "Questions on $\emptyset$ ..." :-P

Comment: oh, MathJax now works (even in comments)

Comment: Geoff fixed this. Just a heads-up: we're rolling out new close-reason code *tomorrow*, so enjoy the new-old ones while you can...

Comment: The [Meta.SE] post about the new closing system that Shog9 mentioned above: [closing changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons)